How to use Nested Projections with Native Query
I Recently Upgraded my Application from Spring Boot 1.5.8 to 2.2.12 and started encountering this error. I'm using hibernate 5.2.17.FINAL
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: 
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query fr.econsulting.gsc.core.data.model.ContactGroupAccountTemp]
for value '{6bfb7541088a926b, 101466981364550601109, harshit.goyal@unthinkable.co, 2024-04-10 15:05:53.863, 2024-04-10 15:05:53.87, true, 584a009a, null, null, true, READ_ONLY, null}'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException:
No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type 
[@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query fr.econsulting.gsc.core.data.model.ContactGroupAccountTemp]

This is the Repository Class and the Method on which I'm getting the exception
public interface JpaContactGroupAccountTempRepository extends JpaRepository<JpaContactGroupAccountTemp, ShareMetaId> {

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM \"CONTACT_GROUP_ACCOUNT_TEMP\"  where \"TARGET_ID\" = :email AND \"CODE\" = :invitationCode", nativeQuery = true)
List<ContactGroupAccountTemp> isAuthorizedUserByInvitationCode(@Param("invitationCode") String invitationCode, @Param("email") String email);  

}

This is my Entity Class
@Entity
@Table(name = "`CONTACT_GROUP_ACCOUNT_TEMP`", indexes = {
    @Index(columnList = "`GROUP_ID`,`TARGET_ID`")
})
@IdClass(TempShareMetaId.class)
public class JpaContactGroupAccountTemp extends JpaModel<ShareMetaId>
    implements ContactGroupAccountTemp {

    @Id
    private String ownerId;

    @Id
    private String groupId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "`TARGET_EMAIL`", nullable = false, length = 32)
    private String targetId; // email of the target user

    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "`GROUP_ID`", referencedColumnName = "`GROUP_ID`", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "`OWNER_ID`", referencedColumnName = "`OWNER_ID`", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = JpaContactGroup.class)
    private ContactGroup contactGroup;

    @Column(name = "`ROLE`", length = 12, nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ContactGroupRole role = ContactGroupRole.READ_ONLY;


    @Column(name = "`ADD_TO_CONTACT`",
        nullable = false,
        columnDefinition = "boolean default false"
    )
    private Boolean addToContact = false;

    @Column(name = "`CODE`",
        nullable = false, length = 28)
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "`TYPE`")
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "`INDIVISUAL_SHARED`",
        nullable = false,
        columnDefinition = "boolean default true"
    )
    private boolean indivisualShared = true;

    @Column(name = "`HIDDEN_FIELDS`")
    @Lob
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")
    private String hiddenFields = null;

    @Column(name = "`GSC_HIDDEN_FIELDS`")
    private String gscHiddenFields = null;

    protected JpaContactGroupAccountTemp() {
    }

    // domin group or individual group
    public JpaContactGroupAccountTemp(String masterAccountId, String groupId, String slaveAccountEmail, boolean indivisualShared) {
        this.ownerId = masterAccountId;
        this.groupId = groupId;
        this.targetId = slaveAccountEmail;
        this.code = UUID.randomUUID().toString().split("-")[0];
        this.indivisualShared = indivisualShared;
    }

    // individual group
    public JpaContactGroupAccountTemp(String masterAccountId, String groupId, String slaveAccountEmail, String code, boolean indivisualShared) {
        this.ownerId = masterAccountId;
        this.groupId = groupId;
        this.targetId = slaveAccountEmail;
        this.code = code;
        this.indivisualShared = indivisualShared;
    }

    @Override
    public ContactGroup getContactGroup() {
        return this.contactGroup;
    }

    public void setContactGroup(ContactGroup contactGroup) {
        this.contactGroup = contactGroup;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTargetId() {
        return this.targetId;
    }

    @Override
    public ContactGroupRole getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }

    public void setRole(ContactGroupRole role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getAddToContact() {
        return this.addToContact == null ? false : this.addToContact;
    }

    public void setAddToContact(Boolean addToContact) {
        this.addToContact = addToContact;
    }

    @Override
    public ShareMetaId getId() {
        return new ShareMetaId(this.ownerId, this.groupId, this.targetId);
    }

    @Override
    public String getOwnerId() {
        return ownerId;
    }

    public void setOwnerId(String ownerId) {
        this.ownerId = ownerId;
    }

    public void setTargetId(String targetId) {
        this.targetId = targetId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(String groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public boolean isIndivisualShared() {
        return indivisualShared;
    }

    public void setIndivisualShared(boolean indivisualShared) {
        this.indivisualShared = indivisualShared;
    }

    @Override
    public String getHiddenFields() {
        return hiddenFields;
    }

    public void setHiddenFields(String hiddenFields) {
        this.hiddenFields = hiddenFields;
    }

    @Override
    public String getGscHiddenFields() {
        return gscHiddenFields;
    }

    public void setGscHiddenFields(String gscHiddenFields) {
        this.gscHiddenFields = gscHiddenFields;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "JpaContactGroupAccountTemp{" +
            "groupId='" + groupId + '\'' +
            ", ownerId='" + ownerId + '\'' +
            ", targetEmail='" + targetId + '\'' +
            ", role=" + role +
            ", addToContact=" + addToContact +
            ", code='" + code + '\'' +
            ", type='" + type + '\'' +
            '}';
    }
}

This the Owning Side of the Interface Projection
public interface ContactGroupAccountTemp extends ShareMeta {

    ContactGroup getContactGroup();

    String getTargetId();

    ContactGroupRole getRole();

    boolean getAddToContact();

    String getOwnerId();
}

I tried to explore the issue and found that Projections Doesn't work quite well with Native Queries but I also found that nested projections can work with Native Queries but here in my case it isn't happening. I got to know about using @SqlResultSetMapping and ConstructorResult but don't want to go with that. I also removed nested projections but still getting the error. What I'm not able to understand is that this projection with native query was working quite well with spring boot 1.5.8 but suddenly started giving this exception at spring boot 2.2.12. I want to know the reason for that but didn't get any answer to it, what changed in hibernate or spring data jpa. Please tell me what am I doing wrong here and how to use Interface Projection with Native Query.
